# Filter List<> object without using foreach loop in C#2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How we can filter the object in List<> in C#?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's say we have a `List<string>` and you want only the items where the length of the string is greater than 5.

The code below will return a `List<string>` with the results:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("hello");
myList.Add("world!");
myList.Add("one");
myList.Add("large!!");
List<string> resultList = myList.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.Length > 5; });
```

resultList will containt 'world!' and 'large!!'.
This example uses an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx). It can also be written as:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
// ..
List<string> resultList = myList.FindAll(OnlyLargerThanFive);

//..

private static bool OnlyLargerThanFive(string s)
{
  return s.Length > 5;
}
```

The delegate above, OnlyLargerThanFive, is also called a [Predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx).

Comment: Nice solution but won't this internally use a foreach anyway? though I assume Kthevar just meant he didn't want to do the iterating himself

Comment: New to lamdas, how come you cant do myList.FindAll(l => l.Length > 5)

Comment: @RobV: It does a 'normal' 'for' loop internally. Correct me if I'm wrong, anyone.

Comment: okay you can, it just didnt come up in the intellisense is all. Doh

Comment: @Nick Allen: The question is for C# 2.0 which doesn't have lambda syntax for anonymous delegates.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to use lambda:

```
List<Item> l;
l.FindAll(n => n.Something == SomethingElse);
```

It may use internally foreach, but you can't really filter without iterating for whole list.

Comment: Question is meant for 2.0 where lamda is not supported

Answer (score 3):

List<>.Find (gives the first matching occurence) and List.FindAll() gives all matching occurences. 
An example with a list of complex types would is as follow:

I have a class Report:

```
public class Report
{
    public string ReportName;
    public ReportColumnList ReportColumnList;
}
```

and a list of Report

```
List<Report> reportList;
```

To find items in the list where ReportName = 'MyReport', the code would be:

```
string reportName = "MyReport";
List<Report> myReports = reportList.FindAll(delegate(Report obj) { return obj.ReportName == reportName; });
```

To get the first report:

```
Report rc = reportList.Find(delegate(Report obj) { return obj.ReportName == reportName; });
```

Note that the object passed to the delegate should be of the **type with which the list is populated**.

Answer (score 2):

besides the way told by [@Razzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38889/razzie) you can also use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx).

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("hello");
myList.Add("world!");
myList.Add("one");
myList.Add("large!!");

var filtered=from s in myList where s.Length > 5 select s;
```

PS:- **IS ONLY POSSIBLE IN .NET 3 and above**

Comment: He was talking about C# 2.0, which doesn't have LINQ. Other than that, you are correct (though I would use the lambda syntax in this example)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx).  I haven't tested this, but I believe it'll filter down the elements of my list of pie fillings to show only those that start with a "P":

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("Apple");
list.Add("Peach");
list.Add("Chocolate");
list.Add("Pear");
list.Add("Pumpkin");
list.Add("Cherry");
list.Add("Coconut");


var filteredOnes = from item in list
                   where item.StartsWith("P")
                   select item;
```

Comment: Totally blew by the fact that the OP had said C# 2.0.  Definitely doesn't have LINQ, but this would work if the OP upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) like this.

`List<string> List = new List<string> { "i", "am", "using", "LINQ!" };`
`List<string> result = myList.Where(s => s.Length > 3).ToList();`

**it's working only in .net 3 and above.**