# Legacy collection querying before LINQ

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to give a talk about LINQ, and wanted to mention how querying collections used to work. Back in .Net 1.1, I seem to remember there being a method (Find() maybe?) where you would pass the address of another method which would interrogate each item in the collection and determine whether it should be included in the filtered collection.

Am I completely misremembering this? It stuck with me, as the syntax was unusual for the time.

I thought it was something like:

```
public bool ContainsFoo(string term){
    if(term.contains("Foo"){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you could call it like:

```
 filteredCollection = collection.Find(ContainsFoo);
```

I seem to remember a lot of people commenting on how LINQ was so much faster to code because developers could now write functions in-line. How were we writing functions "out-line" previously?

Comment: just iterating over the collection

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897466/filter-list-object-without-using-foreach-loop-in-c2-0

Comment: You might be thinking about [Array.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which takes a predicate. Before lambda expressions ("functions in-line"), you could pass [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) to such methods.

Comment: Was there any way to do this prior to generics? Maybe I have the generation of .Net wrong, and this wasn't around until 2.0

Comment: @ChrisHardie yes, my answer mentioned `List<T>` but the same method is available for `List`, I have updated it to clarify that.

Comment: I don't think List was around in 1.1, I must be confused about the generation.

Comment: @ChrisHardie no, 1.1. you had `ArrayList`.

Comment: Of course, Find only represents a part of the query comprehensions. If you just wanted to get by id, Find may actually be better (faster) than Where (still). However, when you want to compose more complex operations (OrderByDescending/Group/Join/etc.) things get messy real quick, hence the beauty of LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before LINQ you were just limited to all the built-in `List`/`List<T>` methods, and yes [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) is one of them (still is). The difference is it expects a `Predicate<T>` as opposed to a `Func<Boolean, T>` which you can still do inline e.g.

```
var found = list.Find(delegate(Item item) { return item != null; });
```

Or as you demonstrated by using a named method.

Comment: Was going to post this in a separate answer, but will mention it here instead; MSDN documents `List(T).Find` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.80).aspx